# MVC and include template by script tag

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a very simple include work with angular but it tries to find an action by the name test. How do you make it use the script tag and therefor throw a 404:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="test">
    <div>dfdd</div>

</script>

<ul ng-app="fileshareApp" ng-controller="TreeController" >
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include src="'test'"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ng-include="'test'"`?

Comment: Nopes dosent work. MVC will then be looking for an action and return 404 and not the script tag's content :(

Comment: This code is looking fine, I have tried it on Plunker and no problem in getting template. Provide more code for clarity.

Comment: I think its MVC that is the problem. There is no more code. But in crome console following are printed: angular.js:12701 GET https://localhost:44338/test 404 (). Its like MVC interpreets it as a request to another action/controller.